# Trying to loop numbers from 1-100 with 3 numbers on a seperate line

Tags: c#

Trying to loop numbers from 1-100 with 3 numbers on a seperate line

it should look like this:

0 1 2

3 4 5

6 7 8

9 10 11
...
......

100 101 102

and so on, any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion. Write some code that makes an effort to loop from 1-100, outputting three numbers per line. When you run into problems, ask a question here that includes that code and explain the problem, and we can try to help.

Comment: Ive tried to make forloop from 1-100 and then put ToString("000"); but that just make it 3 digits with 0 before, like 001, 002 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple loop and [Modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     Console.Write(i + " ");
     if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Or without Modulus:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=3)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",i,i+1,i+2);
 }
```

Comment: Almost, but this will put the first line break after just one element. Try `i % 3 == (3-1)`

Comment: You did the guys homework...

Comment: hehehehe user1767754 :)